# PHP session expiration while the user is still on the website

Tags: php, session

I am a PHP novice and am trying to wrap my head around how sessions work. I had a general question about the behavior of sessions in php.

So I understand that every time session_start() is called the garbage collector may be invoked with a certain probability. So my first question is, lets say I only have 100 users of my website, and there are 2000 sessions stored in the session.save_path() folder on the web-server. If user A who is one of the 100 users logs in to the website and session_start() is invoked, are one of the previous sessions of user A destroyed or one of the 2000 sessions that belong to all the users destroyed?

My second question is, lets say user A is on the website for about 30 minutes and 'session.gc_maxlifetime' is set to 1440 seconds which is 24 minutes, after 24 minutes is there a chance the user A's session might be deleted by the garbage collector even though the user is still active on the website?

And if so is a new session with all the same information of the previously deleted session started every 24 minutes since this would have to be the case for prevention of loss of user data.

I apologize if these questions sound very rudimentary but I am quite confused about the session concept and would like the concept clarified.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's session garbage collector runs with a probability defined by session.gc_probability divided by session.gc_divisor. By default this is 1/100, which means that above timeout value is checked with a probability of 1 in 100.

This means whenever a new session is started, there is a chance that garbage collector is triggered. Than all sessions that are older then the maxlifetime will be deleted

If someone is active on the site this session will never deleted. On every page refresh the actual session will be reset the lifetime of this session. Only not used sessions will be deleted. So if a user is just idling on the page and do nothing, this session could be deleted. And he have to start a new session.

I hope this helps you understand session

Comment: In regards to the original poster's question about sessions for 'User A' vs. all users - when garbage collection is run, this affects all sessions. PHP can't differentiate between a new session for a user vs. a new arbitrary user.

Comment: I had a follow up question to Benjamin's question. I was wondering whether the session lifetime is reset on every page refresh or whether a whole new session is started after each page refresh? Because when a page is refreshed the code is re-run and the session_start() is also run.

Comment: session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one.This function returns TRUE if a session was successfully started, otherwise FALSE. so if a session is allready startet it dont will start a new one

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection applies to ALL sessions, because PHP has no knowledge of session "ownership"; all session objects that are modified before `time() - ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime')` will be removed.

Whenever a particular session object is accessed using `session_start()`, at the end of the request (implicit) or when `session_write_close()` is called (explicit), its modification time (should) get updated. This means that as long as a user keeps loading pages occasionally, the session is not destroyed.

Btw, I talk about session objects rather than files because the physical storage of sessions can be changed using `session_set_save_handler()`.